# Python transfering from matrix to vector, odd result

Tags: python, matrix, vector, row

I have a 100 images named 1 to 100, I want to read each image into a matrix A, and then fit the matrix A into a row vector of another matrix B. Pretty simple.

Each one of those images is 768x512=393216 and i have a 100 images, so my matrix B should be 100x393216 (each image is one row)

Here is my code:

```
dimensions=(100,393216)
B=np.zeros(dimensions)
for i in range(1,101):
    A=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/DB/%s.ppm' %(i)))
    for j in range(0,768):
        l=0
        for k in range(0,512):
            B[i-1][l]=A[j][k]
            l=l+1
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. But it doesn't. in the end of this process, the matrix A is not the last row of the matrix B.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is resetting `l` every time you jump from row to row within an image, so you are creating a matrix sized 100x512, and every time you iterate over another row, you write over what you wrote previously.  Simply move `l=0` to outside of the for loop that iterates over rows.

```
dimensions=(100,393216)
B=np.zeros(dimensions)
for i in range(1,101):
    A=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/DB/%s.ppm' %(i)))
    l=0
    for j in range(0,768):
        for k in range(0,512):
            B[i-1][l]=A[j][k]
            l=l+1
```